# Changing column names in Shiny datatables

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the column headers of a shiny datatable. This is what I have done so far. I have added comments to code in the server section. I am trying to change column names and limit the selection of rows to single.

```
 addr <- as.data.table(read.csv("addresses.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, div(DT::dataTableOutput("addressTable"), style="font-family:verdana", align="left"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, div(textOutput("selectedAddress"), align="center"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
      # output$addressTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      #   names(addr) [1:4]<- c("STREET ADDRESS","CITY NAME","PROVINCE","POSTAL CODE")
      #   addr
      # }) -- This code works, I was able to change the column headers but not able to add the selection single option.

      output$addressTable <- DT::renderDataTable(addr, selection = 'single') - this code works with the selection to single, but not able to change column headers.

}    
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible by using the `dput` function to include a [mcve] of your dataset?

Comment: I just was able to figure it out, I added the names(addr) [1:4]<- c("STREET ADDRESS","CITY NAME","PROVINCE","POSTAL CODE") just below the read.csv line and then the single line code in the server function worked. Thanks @divibisan for the speedy response.

Comment: Ah, so you just wanted to change the actual colnames of your data.frame, not to have a different display name. Glad you figured it out!